# add space to batch file

Tags: batch-file

How my batch can process space in path example:

C:\Documents and Settings\K\Desktop\New Folder

```
@echo off
pushd "%~dp0"
IF EXIST "%1" GOTO DECODE_INDIVIDUAL

:DECODE_MULTIPLE
xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y "%cd%\encoded" "%cd%\decoded\"
dir "%cd%\decoded\*.php"  /A:-D /B /O:N /S >> "%cd%\filelist.txt"

@echo on
for /F %%e in ("%cd%\filelist.txt") do ( copy "%%e" "bin\file.php" && "php.exe" "bin\decoder.php" "bin\file.php" && move "bin\file.php" "%%e" && del "bin\file.php")
del /Q "%cd%\filelist.txt"
GOTO DECODE_END

:DECODE_INDIVIDUAL
@echo on
"php.exe" "%cd%\bin\decoder.php" "%1"

:DECODE_END
```

Comment: Is the path being passed through `%1` or as the `%CD%`?  Note: Change your `"%1"` to `"%~1"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /F "USEBACKQ delims=" %%e in .....
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set delimiters to nothing, if you have spaces in path or file names:

```
for /F "usebackqdelims=" %%e in ("%cd%\filelist.txt") do ( copy "%%~e" "bin\file.php" && "php.exe" "bin\decoder.php" "bin\file.php" && move "bin\file.php" "%%~e" && del "bin\file.php")
```

You should use better `%%~z` than `%%z`, the `~` does remove additional double quotes.

Edited according Peter Wright's answer.

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\K\Desktop\DECODER>(copy "C:\Documents" "bin\file.php"
  && "php.exe" "bin\decoder.php" "bin\file.php"   && move "bin\file.ph
p" "C:\Documents"   && del "bin\file.php" )
        1 file(s) copied.

<br>bin\file.php: errorCould Not Find C:\Documents and Settings\K\Desktop\DECODE
R\bin\file.php